# Behat - Laravel - CAS login user feature test

Tags: php, laravel, cas, behat

I am writing features using Behat in my Laravel projects.
My scenarios are just to check if the user is logged in through CAS system successfully or fail.

```
  Scenario: Authentication
    Given I am on the homepage
    And I press "Login" button
    Then I should see "Login Successfully"
```

However, it's not working as I expected. 
Any idea?

Thanks much

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting? and maybe the html snippet of the element used in the step that is failing.

Comment: @lauda I got this error: "<b>Error</b>: <font color="FF0000"><b>Internal script failure</b><br />"

Comment: Check this manual and see if is working and if you need any user-password, maybe you have an environment bug/issue, as for the error if everything should work ok it would help the error received in behat.

Comment: @lauda Thanks. I already checked the when i run it in web browser. CAS is still running fine in real web browser. Do u think Mink is not able to redirect page correctly ?

Comment: If you are getting `Internal script failure` then it is possible the redirect is not done. If you are testing UI you should use `@javascript` and `@insulated` feature tags before `Feature` keyword.

Comment: @lauda thanks for your suggestion. Seems like it not works. I tried rebuild my whole vagrant. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that one of my colleague found, and implemented successful

app/Http/CASAuth.php

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class MiamiCASAuth
{

    protected $auth;
    protected $cas;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        if(strcmp(env(“APP_ENV”),“acceptance”) !== 0) {
          $this->auth = $auth;
          $this->cas = app(‘cas’);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(strcmp(env("APP_ENV"),"acceptance") !== 0) {
            if ($this->cas->isAuthenticated()) {
                // Store the user credentials in a Laravel managed session
                session()->put('cas_user', $this->cas->user());

            } else {
                if ($request->ajax()) {
                    return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
                }
                $this->cas->authenticate();
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php

```html
/**
     * @Given /^I am logged in as "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function iAmLoggedInAs($id)
    {
        if (Session::isStarted()) {
            Session::regenerate(true);
        } else {
            Session::start();
        }

        // Set server session
      
        Session::put('cas_user', $id);
        
        // Set client cookie
        $minkSession = $this->getSession();
        $minkSession->setCookie(Session::getName(), Crypt::encrypt(Session::getId()));
    }
```

```html
Scenario: login
Given I am logged in as "trinhdh"
And I am on the homepage
Then the response should contain "Logged in as: Trinh Daniel"
```

That should works.